# Multi Thread UPD

Tags: java

I would like to know how I could make this a thread? So that I can spawn a thread from my server class each time some client connects. I could then go on to make it Multi threaded. My question is simply how easy , or hard would it be to now make this part runnable,  without destroying the structure of the whole program.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Client {



    static double difference=0;
    static int totalTransferred=0;
    static StartTime timer;
    static double previousTimeElapsed=0;
    static int sizeDifference=0;
    static int previousSize=0;


    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        final int lossRate = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        final String hostName = args[1];
        final int port = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        final String fileName = args[3];
        final String destFileName = args[4];
        setUp(hostName, port, fileName, destFileName);
    }

    public static void setUp(String hostName, int port, String fileName,String destFileName) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Sending the file");
        //Socket, address and file creation and set up
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(hostName);

        String testString2 =destFileName;
        byte[] bytesData1 = new byte[1024];
        bytesData1 = testString2.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket statPacket1 = new DatagramPacket(bytesData1,bytesData1.length,address,port);
        socket.send(statPacket1);

        File file = new File(fileName); 
        // Create a byte array to store file
        InputStream inFromFile = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] fileByteArray = new byte[(int)file.length()];
        inFromFile.read(fileByteArray);
        // Start timer
        StartTime timer = new StartTime(0);
        // Create the flag to indicate the very last message in the sequence so transmission 
        // can finally halt 
        int sequenceNumber = 0;
        boolean lastMessageFlag = false;
        // Sequence number for acknowledged packets
        int ackSequenceNumber = 0;
        // Create a counter for number of re-transmissions
        int retransmissionCounter = 0;
        // For as each message we will create
        for (int i=0; i < fileByteArray.length; i = i+1021 ) {

            // Increment sequence number
            sequenceNumber += 1;

            // Create message
            byte[] message = new byte[1024];

            // Set the first and second bytes of the message to the sequence number
            message[0] = (byte)(sequenceNumber >> 8);
            message[1] = (byte)(sequenceNumber);

            // Set flag to 1 if packet is last packet and store it in third byte of header
            if ((i+1021) >= fileByteArray.length) {
                lastMessageFlag = true;
                message[2] = (byte)(1);
            } else { // If not last message store flag as 0
                lastMessageFlag = false;
                message[2] = (byte)(0);
            }

            // Copy the bytes for the message to the message array
            if (!lastMessageFlag) {
                for (int j=0; j <= 1020; j++) {
                    message[j+3] = fileByteArray[i+j];
                }
            }
            else if (lastMessageFlag) { // If it is the last message
                for (int j=0;  j < (fileByteArray.length - i)  ;j++) {
                    message[j+3] = fileByteArray[i+j];          
                }
            }

            // Send the message
            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length, address, port);

            socket.send(sendPacket);

           totalTransferred=sendPacket.getLength()+totalTransferred;
           totalTransferred = Math.round(totalTransferred);

           if(Math.round(totalTransferred/1000)% 50==0)
              {
                  System.out.println("");
                  System.out.println("");
                  System.out.println("-----------------------------");
                  System.out.println("Milestone Statistics");
                  sizeDifference = totalTransferred/1000-previousSize;
                  System.out.println("We just transferred another: " + sizeDifference+"Kb");
                  difference = timer.getTimeElapsed()-previousTimeElapsed;
                  System.out.println("You have now transferred "+Math.round(totalTransferred/1000)+"Kb");
                  System.out.println("Time taken so far: "+timer.getTimeElapsed()/1000+" Seconds");
                  previousTimeElapsed= timer.getTimeElapsed();
                  previousSize=totalTransferred/1000;
                  double throughput = totalTransferred/1000/timer.getTimeElapsed();
                  System.out.println("Throughput average so far :"+throughput+" Mbps");
                  System.out.println("Throughput for last 50: " + sizeDifference/difference+" Mbps");
                  System.out.println("------------------------------");
                  System.out.println("");
                  System.out.println("");

              }




            System.out.println("Sent: Sequence number = " + sequenceNumber);

            // For verifying the the packet 
            boolean ackRecievedCorrect = false;
            boolean ackPacketReceived = false;

            //The acknowledgment is not correct 
            while (!ackRecievedCorrect) {
                // Create another packet by setting a byte array and creating data gram packet
                byte[] ack = new byte[2];
                DatagramPacket ackpack = new DatagramPacket(ack, ack.length);

                try {
                    //set the socket timeout for the packet acknowledgment
                    socket.setSoTimeout(50);
                    socket.receive(ackpack);
                    ackSequenceNumber = ((ack[0] & 0xff) << 8) + (ack[1] & 0xff);
                    ackPacketReceived = true;

                    //double time = timer.getTimeElapsed();

                }
                catch (SocketTimeoutException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Socket timed out waiting for the ");
                    ackPacketReceived = false;
                }

                // Break if there is an acknowledgment next packet can be sent
                if ((ackSequenceNumber == sequenceNumber) && (ackPacketReceived)) 
                {   

                    ackRecievedCorrect = true;
                    System.out.println("Ack received: Sequence Number = " + ackSequenceNumber);
                    break;


                }

                // Re send the packet
                else
                { 
                    socket.send(sendPacket);
                    System.out.println("Resending: Sequence Number = " + sequenceNumber);
                    // Increment retransmission counter
                    retransmissionCounter += 1;
                }


            }


        }

        //Socket is closed now transmission is complete

        System.out.println("File " + fileName + " has been sent");
        // Calculate statistics

        double fileSizeKB = (fileByteArray.length) / 1024;
        double transferTime = timer.getTimeElapsed() / 1000;
        double fileSizeMB = fileSizeKB/1000;
        double throughput = fileSizeMB/transferTime;



        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Statistics of transfer");
        System.out.println("------------------------------");
        System.out.println("File " + fileName + " has been sent successfully.");
        System.out.println("The size of the File was "+totalTransferred/1000+ " KB");
        System.out.println("This is approx: "+totalTransferred/1000/1000+ " MB");
        System.out.println("Time for transfer was " +timer.getTimeElapsed()/1000+ " Seconds");
        System.out.printf("Throughput was %.2f MB Per Second\n",+throughput);
        System.out.println("Number of retransmissions: " + retransmissionCounter);  
        System.out.println("------------------------------");




        String testString ="File Size: "+fileSizeMB+"mb\n"+"Throughput: "+throughput+" Mbps"
                +"\nTotal transfer time: "+transferTime+" Seconds";
        byte[] bytesData = new byte[1024];
        bytesData = testString.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket statPacket = new DatagramPacket(bytesData,bytesData.length,address,port);
        socket.send(statPacket);


        socket.close();
    }










}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like that. Please check if it stills remains any static reference inside setUp method.

```
public class Client implements Runnable{

    private int lossRate;
    private String hostName;
    private int port ;
    private String fileName ;
    private String destFileName;

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Client client= new Client();
     client.lossRate = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
     client.hostName = args[1];
     client.port = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
     client.fileName = args[3];
     client.destFileName = args[4];

    Thread thread new Thread(client);
    setUp(hostName, port, fileName, destFileName);
}


public void run(){

      setUp();
}

  public void setUp() throws IOException { same code}
}
```